# What is the proper way to get values from NSDictionaries to separate variables

Tags: swift, for-loop, firebase, nsdictionary

It's not entirely that I can't solve this, but there are proper and improper ways and I don't want to use a flawed method.  I have this snapshot from firebase, and I declare it as NSDictionary as so:

```
let commentDict = commentsDictionary.value as? NSDictionary
```

When I print commentDict it looks like this:

```
    commentText = Fififgkffy;
    postedBy = USXhV0QYkpbSzAmXgfeteXHuoqg2;
    commentText = Fhzifigh;
    postedBy = USXhV0QYkpbSzAmXgfeteXHuoqg2;
```

CommentDict will always look like this.  It will always have 2 items.  I want to know the proper way to grab the items and assign them to variables.  One way I have used before, but just on one item is by putting this in a for loop:

```
if name as! String == "postedBy" {
```

Then I get the value for the "postedBy" dictionary item.  When having 2 items though, should I make a little array for commentText and postedBY, and have 2 arrays with 2 items each?  Another important point is that These must stay in their own groups.  I have to keep track of which "commentText" was the first group and which was the 2nd group, same with "postedBy".

In the long-run I have to end up with commentText1, postedBy1, commentText2, postedBy2 all as separate String variables.

Comment: is it posible to cast to array of NSDictionary? the `commentDict` print value aboce should have `[ ]` i assume

Comment: It does that when you convert firdatasnapshot or w/e into nsdictionary, I think it's kind of like 2 separate dictionaries or something I don't know it's weird

Comment: You know what you can just treat it as one big dictionary.  When I use a for loop like for (name,value) in commentDict, and I print value it prints all the values, so 4 values.  I could just put all 4 of those into an array of strings tbh I mean I don't see how they would ever get out of order.

Comment: I changed it to make up for firebase's weird format.  It's the same as if it didnt' have the curly brackets, just treat it like 1 dictionary with 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing but I just want to know if there is a better or more "proper" way to do it.  I might have to put some safety if statements into this method to make sure the array gets filled properly and all that.

```
if let commentDict = commentsDictionary.value as? NSDictionary {
     for(name, value) in commentDict {
          commentInfoArray.append(value as! String)
     }
     let comment1Text = commentInfoArray[0]
     let comment1User = commentInfoArray[1]
     let comment2Text = commentInfoArray[2]
     let comment2User = commentInfoArray[3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only *postedBy* and *commentText* relation that you are looking for try using this as your structure:-

```
    USXhV0QYkpbSzAmXgfeteXHuoqg2 : comment1 : true,
                                   comment2 : true,
    //postedById : [postText]
```

Then at your retrieval use a dictionary to append your data to:-

```
db_Ref.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

        if let commentDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            for each in commentDict{

                 print(each.key)   // Append your key here

            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Did you give it a shot?